# not enough values to unpack - linear separability using perceptron

Tags: python, machine-learning, perceptron

hi im trying to know whether my data is linearly separable or not..
i took the reference of iris dataset for linear separability (Single Layer Perceptron) from this link ([enter link description here](https://www.tarekatwan.com/index.php/2017/12/methods-for-testing-linear-separability-in-python/#6)) and implemented on mine..

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

dataset = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/jail.csv", delimiter=",") #my data has 13 features. where 13th feature is the target

X= dataset.iloc[:, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]].values 
Y= (dataset.selected == 0).astype(np.int)

sc= StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
perceptron = Perceptron(random_state = 0)
perceptron.fit(X, Y)
predicted = perceptron.predict(X)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(Y, predicted)

plt.clf() 
plt.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.Wistia)
classNames = ['Negative','Positive']
plt.title('Perceptron Confusion Matrix - Entire Data')
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
tick_marks = np.arange(len(classNames))
plt.xticks(tick_marks, classNames, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, classNames)
s = [['TN','FP'], ['FN', 'TP']]

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        plt.text(j,i, str(s[i][j])+" = "+str(cm[i][j]))
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

everything is going right until here but im trying to draw a decision boundary using this code as reference.

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
plt.clf()
X_set, y_set = X, Y
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, perceptron.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('navajowhite', 'darkkhaki')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Perceptron Classifier (Decision boundary for features vs the target)')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

ran the above code and got this error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-2de87affd5bd> in <module>
      4 X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
      5                      np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
----> 6 plt.contourf(X1, X2, perceptron.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
      7              alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('navajowhite', 'darkkhaki')))
      8 plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in predict(self, X)
    279             Predicted class label per sample.
    280         """
--> 281         scores = self.decision_function(X)
    282         if len(scores.shape) == 1:
    283             indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in decision_function(self, X)
    260         if X.shape[1] != n_features:
    261             raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; expecting %d"
--> 262                              % (X.shape[1], n_features))
    263 
    264         scores = safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,

ValueError: X has 2 features per sample; expecting 13


    <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

tried changing it a little according to my code..

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
plt.clf()
X_set, y_set = X, Y
X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2,perceptron.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('navajowhite', 'darkkhaki')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Perceptron Classifier (Decision boundary for Setosa vs the rest)')
plt.xlabel('Petal Length')
plt.ylabel('Petal Width')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

and got this error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-e47fde042987> in <module>
      3 X_set, y_set = X, Y
      4 X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
----> 5                      np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
      6 plt.contourf(X1, X2,perceptron.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
      7              alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('navajowhite', 'darkkhaki')))

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 12, got 2)
```

can any one please help me with this.. im trying to plot a decision boundary. i have no idea how to fix the above code.

expecting something similar to this.

[image]

thank you.

Comment: This problem generally occurs when you return a few values and accept more than that. For eg. your function is returning only two values but you are expecting more than two values. eg. x, y, z = fun(a,b). return a, b; Here you are returning two values but accepting three values. Check your function properly to debug this problem.

Comment: hi @girijesh96 I am honestly stuck here. I looked into many examples but haven't able to fix my code. I am newbie to be honest. could you please help me out on how to fix that error and acquire the desired output. I really need help with this.

Comment: Did you check the values? Look into your function that is giving the error. Check its call back function and return values. It will help you to locate the problem. I can assure that it is a problem of values function is getting in return from the function it is calling. I will need to look into your full code to locate the issue

Comment: I will look into it.. but I have posted my full code here. 
I have 13 features.. where the 13th feature is the target label. it has two classes.. 0 and 1. I used the perceptron example of iris dataset. my data is similar to it but It has 12 features.